# Solr - WhiteSpaceTokenzierFactory: searching for a hyphen returns all data

Tags: solr, fieldtype

I'm using WhiteSpaceTokenzierFactory:

```xml
<fieldType name="newFieldType" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
</fieldType>
```

In my Schema the default search field is using this new field type.
Following query returns all indexed documents:

```
?wt=json&indent=on&start=0&rows=500&q=\*-\*
```

When I use StandardTokenizerFactory, it returns only the documents which have hyphen in them.

Why is the WhitespaceTokenizerFactory returning all data? I have not found any info anywhere online.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post your request handler? The request handler defines the fields that a query will be run on. Probably that handler targets somewhere else?

Comment: The default filed is correct in request handler.

Comment: actually it's really weird query \*-\*, why you use it?